# Service pack for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, installation

I have ArcGIS 10.2 installed on my machine which shows service pack 0 (build 0), i want to upgrade my service pack to 3 or higher possibly 5. I downloaded service pack 5 for ArcGIS 10 because i did not find service packs for 10.2. Whie i install the service pack 5, it shows " The service patch cannot be installed by the windows Installer service because program to be upgraded may be missing. or the upgrade patch may update a different version of the program. Verify that the proram to be be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade patch."
Is there any service pack available for 10.2?

Comment: 10.2.2 was the terminal release of ArcGIS 10.2.  There are [dozens of patches published for 10.2.2 use](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/list?productid=66&productVersions=10.2.2&categoryTypes=5&categoryTypes=8), but the base 10.2.2 media must be obtained from the customer service portal.

Answer (score 5):

Installing a service pack for ArcGIS 10 will NOT work with ArcGIS version 10.2. You must download and install patches and packs for your specific version.

There is an array of different patches but I don't believe there is an actual service pack for 10.2. At least I can't fin one **[here](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/list?productid=160&productVersions=10.4&productVersions=10.3.1&productVersions=10.3&productVersions=10.2.2&productVersions=10.2.1&productVersions=10.2&productVersions=10.1&productVersions=10&categoryTypes=5)**

To upgrade you would have needed to purchase a newer version or pay yearly maintanance fee which allows you to allows you to download new versions as they come out.  It used to be that in older versions ESRI released service regular service packs but now they are forcing users to upgrade although some patches are still available [**here**](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/list?productid=160&productVersions=10.2&categoryTypes=8)

Comment: Agreed, from everything I've heard, ESRI is no longer releasing service packs, just critical patches and and complete new software versions.  Instead of releasing new versions every couple of years and service packs every couple of quarters, they are releasing new versions every year and doing away with service packs.  Trying to give more incentive to keeping annual maintenance current.

Answer (score 0):

There are no servicepacks for ArcGIS 10.2 as such, but versions 10.2.1 and 10.2.2 *do* exist. These could arguably be called 'servicepacks' or 'full versions', take your pick.

You should be able to download the installers from https://my.esri.com if you have a proper subscription. But unless you have a very specific reason to stick with 10.2.x, I would recommend to go for 10.3 or 10.4.